# Creating filter using .map and store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, store

I'm trying to make a filter for my restaurantsAll. The code works without the filter but when I try to add the filter I get this error: TypeError: restaurant.toLowerCase is not a function | Line 25

When I use a:

`const list = ['jef', 'uwmoeder']`    and      `list.map`
it does work but with the store. it doesn't

Can someone take a look at it please?

```
   <ul>
        {store.restaurants.map(restaurant => {
          if (filter.lenght !== 0) {
            if (restaurant.toLowerCase().startsWith(filter.toLowerCase())) {
              return (
                <li>
                  <Restaurant
                    restaurant={restaurant}
                    key={restaurant.id}
                    onClick={() => {
                      uiStore.setCurrentRestaurant(restaurant);
                      uiStore.setCurrentView(VIEWS.detail);
                    }}
                  />
                </li>
              );
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          }
          return (
            <li>
              <Restaurant
                restaurant={restaurant}
                key={restaurant.id}
                onClick={() => {
                  uiStore.setCurrentRestaurant(restaurant);
                  uiStore.setCurrentView(VIEWS.detail);
                }}
              />
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
```

this is the component Restaurant:

```
const Restaurant = ({restaurant, onClick}) => {
  return useObserver(() => (
    <div className={style.restaurantlist} >
      <Link to={`/detail/${restaurant.id}`}>
      <img onClick={onClick} className={style.restaurantfoto} src={restaurant.picture} alt={restaurant.name} />
      </Link>

      <section className={style.information}>
        <Information restaurant={restaurant} />
      </section>


    </div>
  ));
}
```

Comment: You need to include all the necessary information ([mcve]) inside the question itself, not just hosted elsewhere.

Comment: `filter.lenght`? Is this a valid property on your `filter` object? What is the value or object type of `restaurant` within the map callback? If it isn't a string than the error makes sense. Based upon usage later in `Restaurant` is appears to be an object, not a string.

Comment: @DrewReese I edited the post and added the `Restaurant` component

Comment: @EmileBergeron fixed it, thanks

Comment: What is the defined `PropTypes` shape of the prop `restaurant`? That is what you access like a string in line 25, but later access like an object in line 29/30 & 45/46.

Comment: @DrewReese : `Restaurant.propTypes = {
  restaurant: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
`

Comment: Well, that is a most helpful proptype definition. May as well be `PropTypes.any` or nothing at all. So what are you trying to `toLowerCase()`?  Please drop a `debugger;` or `console.log(restaurant);` at line 25 before you try `restaurant.toLowerCase()` and examine what the *actual* object shape of `restaurant` is.

Comment: If I `console.log` my restaurant appears without an issue.

Comment: @DrewReese okay I spelled length wrong lmao. Now I can see my restaurants but when I start filtering I get the error

Comment: Please update question with the output from the console log so that we may see what the actual shape of the `restaurant` object is. Or share what the shape of `store.restaurants` is.